# Can't list git repositories in subfolders

Tags: git, gitolite

I have a gitolit server with the following structure:

```
/home/user/repository/test.git
/home/user/repository/folder1/a.git
/home/user/repository/folder1/subfolder1/b.git
/home/user/repository/folder2/c.git
```

This is just an example, there are several folders and subfolders.

When I want to list all the repositories with the command

```
ssh git@server info
```

I'm only able to list the repository located in the root folder, that is:

```
/home/user/repository/test.git
```

But I can't see all the other ones.

Is there any reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

From gitolite's [website](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/user.html#the-info-command),

> **the info command**
>
> The only command that is always available to every user is the info command (run ssh git@host info -h for help),
>   which tells you what version of gitolite and git are on the server,
>   and **what repositories you have access to**. The list of repos is very
>   useful if you have doubts about the spelling of some new repo that you
>   know was setup.

Probably you don't have access to those repositories.

Answer (score 1):

As seen in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/h6iKY3pj8BA), you should see the list of all repository, so:

- either you don't have access
- or the [`gitolite.conf` file](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2.html) has *not* declared those repos in their subfolders

If you can access the gitolite.conf folder, you can check that.
Or have an admin use the [`gitolite access` tracing command](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/conf-2.html#tracing-the-access-control-decision), which can check:

- if the repo exists
- what are the rules denying access for a specific user/repo